# React prop disappears

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm obviously not understanding something here when it comes to react/react router 4. I'm trying to check if a user is logged in or out to control the navbar user status routes. I can't seem to access the prop, it just disappears. Can someone point out what I'm not understanding? `isUserLoggedInServerCheck` returns a value at Server, it then returns a value at AppServer, however, at CandidateLanding it returns undefined.

Path: `Server`

```
onPageLoad(sink => {
  let isUserLoggedInServerCheck = false;
  if (sink.request.cookies.sssr) {
    isUserLoggedInServerCheck = true;
  }

  sink.renderIntoElementById(
    'react-target',
    renderToString(
      <AppServer
        location={sink.request.url}
        isUserLoggedInServerCheck={isUserLoggedInServerCheck}
      />
    )
  );
});
```

Path: `AppServer`

```
const AppServer = props => {
  const context = {};
  const { location, isUserLoggedInServerCheck } = props;

  return (
    <StaticRouter context={context} location={location} isUserLoggedInServerCheck={isUserLoggedInServerCheck}>
      <div className="application">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={CandidateLanding} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </StaticRouter>
  );
};
```

Path: `CandidateLanding`

```
function CandidateLanding(props) {
  const { location, isUserLoggedInServerCheck } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar location={location.path} isUserLoggedInServerCheck={isUserLoggedInServerCheck} />
    </div>
  );
}

const CandidateLandingContainer = withTracker(props => {
  const { isUserLoggedInServerCheck } = props;
  if (Meteor.isServer) {
    return {
      isUserLoggedInServerCheck
    };
  }

  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    return {
      isUserLoggedInServerCheck
    };
  }
})(CandidateLanding);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your props to `StaticRouter` and they never make it to the `CandidateLanding` component. The best way to do this would be to use the render function for route

```
<Route path="/" exact render={ (props) => <CandidateLanding {...props} anotherProp={ anotherVariable } />} />
```

Make sure you remove the unnecessary props from Static Router as well.
[Source](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5521)

Answer (score 0):

The `StaticRouter` will not provide the property `isUserLoggedInServerCheck` to its children. One way to achieve this is to use the *react context*. This prevents the requirement to pass the parameter from one competent to the next. To use the context you will need an context instance, `const UserLoggedInContext = React.createContext();` the provider `<UserLoggedInContext.Provider value={isUserLoggedInServerCheck}>` and finally the consumer (useContext) `const isUserLoggedInServerCheck = React.useContext(UserLoggedInContext);` to get the provided value where you need it.

**Example**

```js
const UserLoggedInContext = React.createContext();
const AppServer = props => {
  const context = {};
  const { location, isUserLoggedInServerCheck } = props;

  return (
    <UserLoggedInContext.Provider value={isUserLoggedInServerCheck}>
      <StaticRouter context={context} location={location} >
        <div className="application">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={CandidateLanding} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
        </StaticRouter>
      </UserLoggedInContext.Provider>
    );
};

 // ...

function CandidateLanding(props) {
  const { location } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar location={location.path} />
    </div>
  );
}

const CandidateLandingContainer = withTracker(props => {
  const isUserLoggedInServerCheck = React.useContext(UserLoggedInContext);
  if (Meteor.isServer) {
    return {
      isUserLoggedInServerCheck
    };
  }

  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    return {
      isUserLoggedInServerCheck
    };
  }
})(CandidateLanding);
```

For more details please refer to: [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: React.useContext(UserLoggedInContext), is giving me an error. It says `UserLoggedInContext is not defined`

Comment: Did you try exporting it `export const UserLoggedInContext = React.createContext();` it and imported it where you want to use `import { UserLoggedInContext} from "<your_file_name>"` ?